# Multiple instances override values

Tags: jquery

I've created a very simple jQuery logo rotate plugin, but the second instance is overriding my vlaues from the first instance.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.clientRoll = function(settings) {

      var config = {
        'speed': 10000,
        'items': 3
    };

  var settings = $.extend(config, settings);

  var itemRoll = $(this); 

  var childHeight = $(itemRoll).children().eq(0).outerHeight();
  $(itemRoll).height(childHeight);

  $.fn.clientRollLeft = function() {
    var logoWidth = $(this).children(':first').innerWidth();

    $(this).children(':first').not(':animated').clone().css({ opacity: 0, marginLeft: "" }).insertAfter($(this).children(':last'))/*.delay(200).animate({ opacity: 1 })*/;

    $(this).children(':first').not(':animated').animate({ 
      marginLeft: -(logoWidth), opacity: 0 }, function () {   
        $(this).remove();
    });

    $(this).children(":gt(" + (config.items - 1) + ")").css({ opacity: 0, background: "#FF0" }).delay(300).animate({ opacity: 1, background: "#FFF" });
}

};
})(jQuery);
```

So whenever I write something like this:
    $(".client-roll div > ul").clientRoll({ 'speed': 2000, 'items': 4 });
    $(".article-roll").clientRoll({ 'items': 3, 'speed': 1500 });

The "items" value from the first instance is overriden by the value 3 from the second instance.

Comment: try putting some delay in your animation...

Comment: var itemRoll = $(this);  Then you use it like this: $(itemRoll)  So you are embeding your DOM element two times in a jquery object which is useless. Change it to that: var itemRoll = this;

Comment: @roasted Thanks, I've overseen that.

Answer (score 0):

The [`extend` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) extends the object that you pass as the first parameter, and returns it.

Supply a new object as the first parameter if you want to merge two objects into a new one:

```
var settings = $.extend({}, config, settings);
```

Comment: I've replaced that and now my values are set to default. So nothing really changed, except that they aren't overriden anymore, but set to default instead.

Comment: @twenty: You aren't using the `settings` object anywhere in the code, you are using the `config` object.